# strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: php, warnings

M getting the following warning on my page:

```
"strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"
```

My code is as below:
     a.php:

```
 $x = $_GET['a'];
 $y = $_GET['b'];
 $obj = new TestClass();
 $obj->methodCall($x,$y)
```

TestClass:

```
class TestClass{
   public function methodCall($x,$y){
    if((strcmp('val1',$x) > 0) && (strcmp('val2',$y) >0)){
      //do something
    }
   }
 }
```

Getting the warning at line where I am using strcmp. It looks pretty straight forward, but not able to figure out the problem :(

Comment: Put `var_dump($x, $y);` in the first line in the function and show results here

Comment: string 'car' (length=3)
object(InventoryManager)[2]
  public 'log' => 
    object(KLogger)[3]
      public 'Log_Status' => int 1
      public 'DateFormat' => string 'Y-m-d G:i:s' (length=11)
      public 'MessageQueue' => 
        array
          0 => string 'The log file was opened successfully.' (length=37)
      private 'log_file' => string 'logs/log.txt' (length=12)
      private 'priority' => int 1
      private 'file_handle' => resource(9, stream)
I have a $log being defined as a field in the class, which I am initializing in the constructor. I am expecting the value of $x=car and $y=all

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, the `$y` argument is an object (InventoryManager), and not a string. `strcmp` expects both args to be a string. If the object had a `__toString()` method you could do this:

```
// Cast object $y as a string when passed
// But you would have to check the __toString method to see how the string was being
// built to ensure it's the correct attribute you wish to compare
$object->methodCall($x, (string) $y);
```

Otherwise, I think you may have set the `$_GET['b']` value incorrectly via form submission.

JIC, here is a link to the `strcmp` [docs](https://www.php.net/strcmp).

Comment: I am getting the call thru a URL call of the form :
http://../WS.php?b=car&i=all
and m assigning the values as :
$b = $_GET['b'] ; $i = $_GET['i'] ;

I am passing the values of $b and $i to the method call.. anything wrong in what I have done ?

Comment: No, that is good to go as `$b = 'car'`, and `$i = 'all'`, both of which are strings allowing you to call `strcomp` on either. Although I am confused, you are calling `strcomp('val1', $x)`, which means that it will return a non-zero value if $x is any value but `val1`. Or is `val1` just a placeholder for your example?

Comment: Ahhh, based on your comments, then your code should be good to go. Just make sure the `$_GET` parameters you are localizing from, line-up with what you think they are, before passing to your method. Meaning that `$b` should never be an object, it should be `car`.

Comment: but Mike, doesnt $b=$_GET['b'] make $b a string ? Is there a way to convert it to a string if its not ? i tried $b=$b+'', but no luck :(

Comment: According to the URL you posted earlier, yes `$b = $_GET['b']` will result in `$b = 'car'`. If `$b` is anything but `car`, you have code somewhere overwriting the `car` value.

Comment: Mike.. not yet :( is this wrong :
$b = "";
if(isset($_GET["b"])){
 $b = htmlspecialchars($_GET["b"]);

Thats all I am doing with that variable..

Comment: The code you are posting in these comments is not the same code you posted in your comment in response to zermks. Somewhere along the line, either `$b` value is being over-written with an object (InventoryManager), or, you are calling `methodCall` with the wrong arguments. The code you posted in these comments should work no problem.